# How to calcutate several functions in class without reiteration

Tags: python

I need to calculate some variables, which can be used by other variables:

```
class Variables:
    def __init__(self, param1, param2):
        self._param1 = param1
        self._param2 = param2
    
    def var1(self):
        return self._param1 + 'foo'
    def var2(self):
        return var1() + 'bar'
    ....
    def var9(self):
        return var2() + var8()
    def var10(self):
        return var3() + var9()
```

Problem is that intermediate functions var1..var9 are calculating multiple times when I call them outside module. I tried to calculate them in `__init__`:

```
def var1(self):
    return self._param1 + 'foo'
def var2(self):
    return self._var1 + 'bar'
....
def var9(self):
    return self._var2 + self._var8
def var10(self):
    return self._var3 + self._var9


    class Variables:
        def __init__(self, param1, param2):
            self._param1 = param1
            self._param2 = param2
            
            self._var1 = var1(self)
            self._var2 = var2(self)
            ....
            self._var9 = var9(self)
            self._var10 = var10(self)
```

But my intuition tells me that this decision is terrible: self-s inside and outside class are "different".
For some reasons I need 10 separate functions and cant combine them in one big function. What is the best way to calculate and store them?

Comment: Maybe store them in variables, like `_param1`?

Comment: Why not in-line the code that generates self._var1, and then implement var# methods to just return self._var#?

Comment: If the code was complicated enough to warrant separate class methods, then make the method that generates self._var1 be self._generate_var1()

Comment: @Malcolm var1..var10 are 10-100 lines each

Comment: Do you mean that the code to generate va1 is 10-100 lines long?

Comment: @Malcolm i mean that function var1 might be 10-100 rows, i simplified it to one row for question. Is my solution most obviuos?

Comment: Precalculating the values is definitely the right answer, but there is no need to move the methods outside of the class to do that.  And then you still need methods to access your private values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Variables:
    def __init__(self, param1, param2):
        self._param1 = param1
        self._param2 = param2

        self._var1 = self._generate_var1()
        ... similarly for var2 through var10

    def _generate_var1(self):
        var1 = self._param1 + 'foo'
        return var1

    def var1(self):
        return self._var1

    ... similarly for var2 through var10
```

Comment: Wow, I did not assume that in init you can call the functions below

Comment: In python functions don't get called until the line containing them gets executed.  As long as the function is defined before then python doesn't care when.  This makes for some amazing flexibility with dynamically created methods.  However, it also can lead to long hidden bugs.  You may never know that you have mistyped a method name until that line of code gets invoked, unless you have a good IDE that checks for you.